# In which cases does vtable construction not occur?

Tags: c++, vtable

I've noticed that virtual override is not occurring for some reason in my code. I'm extensively using polymorphism so that I can use constructs like `derived.baseFunc()`, where baseFunc calls a virtual function overriden in `Derived`.

In which cases does vtable construction not occur and polymorphic behavior becomes unreliable?

Note: for a simple case, everything works fine, so code doesn't need to be posted.

**Update**: The vtables look all right. It seems that there's a clusterf**k of namespacing that may be the issue. Plus, copy-pasting the code to new file and removing the namespaces fixes the issue.

Comment: Polymorphism never becomes "unreliable" in a well-formed program. You made a mistake somewhere. It's interesting that you've decided this must be someone else's bug.

Comment: So a simple case works but your program doesn't. Perhaps examining a case of some *intermediate* complexity would provide some enlightenment?

Comment: You might wanna show some code along with statements about what you expect the code to do.

Comment: "code doesn't need to be posted"??

Comment: When you have access to C++11, use the override keyword to let the compiler catch some common mistakes. Other than that, what Tomalak said: polymorphism never becomes unreliable, and unless you provide us with some self-contained code example, we can not point out where you did it wrong.

Comment: Found the bug: Global operator + creates a new instance of the base class by value, so what's returned is a Base object instead of a Derived one.

Answer (score 7):

Since there is no code, it's hard to say something for certain, but here are some wild guesses/options

- You didn't actually override the method. You may think that you have, but in fact you may be mistaken. For example:

  ```
  struct Base{
     virtual int f(int); 
     virtual int g() const;
     virtual ~Base();
  };
  struct Derived: Base{     
     int f();  //doesn't override Base::f
     int g();  //doesn't override Base::g
  };
  ```
- Calling of a virtual function from the constructor doesn't work as you'd expect. For example,

  ```
  struct Base
  {
      Base()
      {
          f();
      }
      virtual void f() {}
      virtual ~Base();
  };
  struct Derived : Base
  {
      void f() { cout << "Derived"; }
  };

  Derived d; //Derived will NOT be printed
  ```
- Some constructs don't invoke virtual dispatch, such as qualified funcion calls:    `ClassName::MethodName()`

In any case, for any polymorphic class the vtable is always there, so don't blame the compiler :)

Comment: *Call of a virtual function from the constructor does not invoke virtual dispatch mechanism!* is not correct & misleading. The virtual dispatch does happen just it doesn't do what one would expect.The `this` in the constructor which is being called always points to the object whos constructor it is, resulting in call to that class'es function.

Comment: To Add to that same is the behavior in case of virtual function being called from destructor of the class.

Answer (score 5):

Any conforming compiler will have proper vtable and polymorphism in place. In properly written code, overriding always happens.

You need to check for some common coding mistakes in your code. For example:

1. Since you said that overriding is not happening for `derived.baseFunc()` kind of cases, check whether `derived` is an object or reference. Remember that runtime polymorphism is applicable only via *pointers & references*.
2. Function signature is important for successful overriding:

   ```
   struct Base
   {
      virtual void foo (int) {}
   };

   struct Derived : Base
   {
      virtual void foo () {} // oops, this `foo` is different than `Base::foo`
   };
   ```

Comment: This is the 3rd down vote without any explanation. 3 down votes for 3 answers with 0 explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is correct, then virtual functions will work as expected. The compiler may, as an optimization, transform virtual function calls into normal function calls if it is 100% certain <strike>about the static type</strike> that the dynamic type is of "static" nature for the scope of this call, i.e. it is certain at compile time that the call happens on a compiletime-known type that cannot change, and thus the function cannot possibly be anything else than exactly one concrete function.
Most of the time, this is the case because you explicitly tell the compiler either with a cast or scope resolution. Regardless, it will *still* work as expected with no observable difference (different machine code and more efficient for sure, but same behaviour).

This is irrespective of generation of a vtable. The vtable is generated anyway (if the compiler uses vtables to implement virtual inheritance, which most/all do, but strictly do not *have* to).

If it does not work as expected, you probably [hide](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9) the virtual function (unintentionally).

Comment: Mostly accurate. In fact virtual dispatch is not used for qualified calls, and optimisation doesn't come into it. Also the compiler would have to be sure of the _dynamic_ type; it already knows the static type.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Yes, maybe the wording is a little bit ambiguous. What I wanted to express with _static_ type is that the _dynamic_ type in the call to be non-virtually dispatched is known to be exactly one type, not possibly anything else, thus "static". Such as `Derived::foo()` or `static_cast<Base>(derived)->foo()` is well-known to be exactly one concrete function, not possibly anything else (the compiler _could_ of course still dispatch the call via the vtable -- it's not strictly illegal -- but it would be nonsensical to do something it doesn't need to do).

Comment: @Damon: It is always a bad idea to "overload" standard c++ terms, even when the intention is a good one.

Comment: Edited post, hopefully less ambiguous now.